# Install vorlon throws "if not defined npm_config_node_gyp" error

Tags: msbuild, socket.io, npm, node-gyp, vorlon

I have a major problem - installation of vorlon is driving me nuts.

I get thins error:

```
C:\Users\[myProfile]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vorlon\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

C:\Users\[myProfile]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vorlon\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk

gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe`   
failed with exit code: 1  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)  
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)  
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit  (internal/child_process.js:200:12)  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\[myProfile]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vorlon\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
```

and I don't knowhow to fix it.

I googled and tried all options that answers for this error proposes.

My situation: 
Win8
command: npm config get prefix returns "C:\Users[myProfile]\AppData\Roaming\npm"

In "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" I have this folders:
12.0
14.0
Microsoft
Microsoft.Cpp

So I have 2 questions about that:
- how to get file Microsoft.Cpp.Props to my drive (with which installation)
- hot to set path that npm will find it

Thanks for any idea about that.